# Query an array with unstructured objects on GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gridsome

I'm trying to use GraphQL to query an unstructured array with objects in Gridsome. It is currently looking very messy and it feels like there should be a better way to do this.

The data that gets loaded into GraphQL from the CMS looks like this:

```
{
    title: "Homepage",
    top_image: "imgurl.jpg",
    page_builder: [
             {
                 type: "slider",
                 field: "data example",
                 different_field: "data example"
             },
              {
                 type: "call_to_action",
                 field_for_cta: "data example",
                 different_cta_field: "data example"
             }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the objects in page_builder will have different fields depening on how the client is building this section.

When I try to query this in GraphQL. It will become very messy:

```
<page-query>
query {
  data: pages(path: "/pages") {
    title,
    top_image,
    page_builder {
      type,
      field,
      different_field,
      type,
      field_for_cta,
      different_cta_field

      #this list will have way more fields depending on all the page builder elements

    }
    }
  }
</page-query>
```

Is there a way to organize this fields by type and only return the fields of this specific type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming gridsome supports fragments, you can do something like this:

```
<page-query>
query {
  data: pages(path: "/pages") {
    title,
    top_image,
    page_builder {
      ...A @include(if: $includeA)
      ...B @include(if: $includeB)
      ...C @include(if: $includeC)
    }
  }
}

# Note: Replace PageBuilderType with appropriate type
fragment A on PageBuilderType {
  # your fields here
}
fragment B on PageBuilderType {
  # your fields here
}
fragment C on PageBuilderType {
  # your fields here
}
</page-query>
```

You can then define the variables when calling `createPage` as shown [here](https://gridsome.org/docs/pages-api/#createpageoptions):

```
api.createPages(({ createPage }) => {
    createPage({
      path: '/my-page',
      component: './src/templates/MyPage.vue',
      queryVariables: {
        includeA: someCondition,
        includeB: someCondition,
        includeC: someCondition,
      },
    })
  })
}
```